# How can the omnibox suggestions be styled in Firefox?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, omnibox

I built an [extension for Chrome](https://chromewebstore.google.com/detail/go/mahkmjlcgkcpkdoonpgjgbbocgegfjhn), which I want to use in Firefox. In chrome one can [style suggestions](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/api/omnibox#type-DescriptionStyleType) using XML-syntax.

Screenshot from Chrome: [image: Example of how the styling looks in chrome]

[Repo](https://github.com/lanijw/go) containing both Chroem and Firefox versions.

I couldn't find anything for Firefox and was wondering whether it was possible, and if so, how? If it's not possible, are there plans to implement this?

I found these three documentation pages and the omnibox extension example.

- [omnibox API overview](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/omnibox)
- [omnibox first steps guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/user_interface/Omnibox)
- [manifest instructions for omnibox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json/omnibox)
- [omnibox example extension](https://github.com/mdn/webextensions-examples/blob/main/firefox-code-search/background.js)

Comment: Can you post your extension code to a GitHub repository?

Comment: While I don't have enough for an actual answer, this does not currently appear possible from within the extension in the way that you desire. The user could choose to style the omnibox by creating a chrome/userChrome.css file in their profile directory, but that wouldn't be on a per-suggestion basis. I provide an example of such a chrome/userChrome.css in my [answer to: "How to get dark themed addressbar search-results"](/a/41623765/3773011), however the instructions there for investigating the Firefox UI DOM are, at this point, quite old and no longer valid.

Comment: @guest271314 Yes, of course. My bad. I just edited my questions description and added a link.

Comment: Here's the Firefox Omnibox details on MDN https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/omnibox